# Matlab interfacing with arduino ERROR

Tags: matlab

I installed the MATLAB support package for arduino in my MATLAB r2013a today.
Now I plugged on my Arduino in my usb port.

And ran the command:

> > a = arduino()
> >
> > Error: Undefined function or variable 'arduino'.

When I get:

> > a = arduino('COM18')
> >
> > Undefined function 'arduino' for input arguments of type 'char'.

I have checked that this package has been installed.
[image: The Screenshot]

It is grey.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks very much

Anupam.

Comment: Is the directory where the arduino package is installed added to the matlab path?

Comment: I a newbie to matlab. Can you please eloborate.I did not change any paths while installing.It was the default one.

Comment: Navigate to the package install dir in matlab and right click you should see the add to path option there. If the dir is on the Matlab path it wont be greyed out

Comment: actually theres a separate Arduino site on stack exchange you might find better help there

Comment: It is grey.See edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino support within MATLAB came with Matlab-2014a onwards, you are using R2013a

Arduino support within SIMULINK came with Matlab-2012a onwards

for your release you can only interact via a simulink model